# File permission resets after reboot (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: permissions

I have an SSD on which Ubuntu 18.04 is installed. I also have a HDD labelled `storage` for storing other data which is owned by root.

I changed the permissions of `storage` by running

```
sudo chown myusername storage
```

This changes the permission but resets automatically after reboot.

How can I make this change permanent?

Comment: Which file system is used on `storage`? Where and how is it mounted?

Comment: 'storage' is mounted on /home/myusername and msdos file system is used in it.

Comment: This helped me, but for a somewhat different issue.
I just wanted to save 'Steam' games to an external disk drive but kept getting the message 'file permissions necessary'. Then I saw Zana's last message, about formatting as ext4. I too formatted in ext4 filesystem, and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved once I formatted the storage HDD with an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: **LQ Reviewers:** This is a self-answer, please VTC Q not A!

Comment: What's wrong with the question? This was the answer...